# Debian machine readable copyright: Files path

Tags: debian

I want to create a machine readable copyright file for a Debian package, as defined in
https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/copyright-format/1.0/#fields .

I have some 3rd party files which are licensed in a different license. Debian recommends using the `Files:` syntax. But I have problems understanding which path I should use.

The line in my `package/debian/rules` file:

```
install -oroot -gstaff -m0644 share/includes/idna_convert.class.php debian/gwhois/usr/share/gwhois/includes/
```

An the target machine, the file is installed on `/usr/share/gwhois/includes/idna_convert.class.php` .

**So, which is the correct usage?**

a)

```
Files: share/includes/idna_convert.class.php
Copyright: 2004-2014, phlyLabs Berlin, http://phlylabs.de
License: LGPL-2.1
```

b)

```
Files: debian/gwhois/usr/share/gwhois/includes/idna_convert.class.php
Copyright: 2004-2014, phlyLabs Berlin, http://phlylabs.de
License: LGPL-2.1
```

c)

```
Files: /usr/share/gwhois/includes/idna_convert.class.php
Copyright: 2004-2014, phlyLabs Berlin, http://phlylabs.de
License: LGPL-2.1
```

Answer (score 2):

`Files` in `debian/copyright` lists files in the source package, before installation. So in your case if I've understood correctly that's option (a), `share/includes/idna_convert.class.php`.